# Android custom Array adapter and database connection

Tags: android, database, sqlite, connection, android-arrayadapter

I couldn't find any solid information regarding this so here it goes;

I am using information from `SQLite` db in my `array adapter` to show/hide a `view`. `Array list` data comes from file system and depending on user's choice a `view` in the row displayed or hidden. So, on `getView` of my `adapter` I open connection, `query db` for that `array item` and if it is in the db I display a view then close db connection.

Is this the right way to do it? It feels like a lot of opening and closing especially if there are many items in the array list. I can open connection on adapter's public constructor but then where would I close it?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid opening and closing the DB so much, you should store the objects retrieved from the DB query in memory, then attach that collection of objects to your adapter.  Then instead of querying the DB everytime getView is called, you should just check your list of query results.

So to sum up, query your DB objects all at once, store them in a collection in memory (as a java ArrayList or something), then refer to the ArrayList when in getView.